# Read records from a table with Optimised Historical Data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a project management app in our organization from which we are getting more than 10ks of records every data in a scheduled process. So in our first database we were storing all these 10K records every day doesn't matter there is any changes in the data. So eventually the table getting bigger and bigger.

So its like this

Extraction Log

```
LogID   ExtractionTime
-------------------------
1        15/01/2021
2        16/01/2021
3        17/01/2021
....
...
..
--------------------------------


PCode       PName         LogId
------------------------------
P1234       Project1      1
P5734       Project2      1
P2785       Project3      1
P5854       Project4      1
P6985       Project5      1
P4748       Project6      1
P2233       Project7      1
P1234       Project1      2
P5734       Project2      2
P2785       Project3      2
P5854       Project4_upd  2
P6985       Project5      2
P4748       Project6      2
P2233       Project7      2
P1234       Project1_upd  3
P2785       Project3      3
P5854       Project4      3
P6985       Project5      3
P4748       Project6      3
P2233       Project7      3
P8464       Project8_New  3
.....
...
..
---------------------------------------
```

Here data getting duplicated for nothing and makes this very tough to manage,

So we have created a new way for handling that like this and in the above example you can see there was very small changes happened in 3 days of extraction

```
PCode       PName         LogId
------------------------------
P1234       Project1      1    N
P5734       Project2      1    N
P2785       Project3      1    N
P5854       Project4      1    N
P6985       Project5      1    N
P4748       Project6      1    N
P2233       Project7      1    N
P5854       Project4_upd  2    U
P1234       Project1_upd  3    U
P8464       Project8_New  3    N
P5734       Project2      3    R
.....
...
..
---------------------------------------
```

Here as you can see we are adding records that changed in last one day and specify that change as well as  N, U or R.

Also concept-wise what we need is to take all data of a specific date we choose.

For example if I choose 17/01/2021 it should return this

```
PCode       PName         LogId
------------------------------
P1234       Project1      1    N
P5734       Project2      1    N
P2785       Project3      1    N
P6985       Project5      1    N
P4748       Project6      1    N
P2233       Project7      1    N
P5854       Project4_upd  2    U
---------------------------------
```

Which means its taking all the records as of that date even when there is only one record for that logID. The same way for logId 3 as well.

But honestly I didn't get a best way to handle this in query because in this sample there are only few data. But in real when time moves there should be lot and so how can we take data of a date in the best way.

Comment: what is `N, U or R` ?

Comment: NEW, UPDATE,REMOVED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you want.

Assuming that `LogId` is incremental, you can based on the required date, get the `LogId` and then get the result. Using `row_number` to only list the latest `LogId` per `PCode`

```
select *
from
(
    select p.PCode, p.PName, p.LogId, p.Change, 
           rn = row_number() over (partition by p.PCode order by p.LogId desc)
    from   Log l
           inner join Project p  on p.LogId < l.LogId
    where  l.ExtractionTime = '2021-01-17'
) p
where p.rn = 1
order by PCode
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e8cae6db860f9a343ad9227b79d77eb)

Comment: THanks a lot.. But its not as I expected. I specified 2021-01-16 . For the the pcode P5854 it should show Project4_upd because its updated in that day (which means for log Id 2). But it shows the data of LogID 1 itself. The same happens for 2021-01-17. it shows only P5854 as updated. But P1234 is updated ,5734 removed and 8464 New which are not in the output

Comment: for `inclusive` then change the condition to `p.LogId <= l.LogId`

Comment: `The same happens for 2021-01-17. it shows only P5854 as updated. But P1234 is updated ,5734 removed and 8464 New which are not in the output` That is not what your expected result looks like in your question.

Comment: THanks a lot <= worked. But actually N,U,R are dynamic. For example we are labeling U automatically if that item was an updatin to an existing record. Same way we are marking New as well. Also if an item removed from the projects we are marking it as R, Sorry to ask, is that possible to achive that.. For example in our case  P5734 is removed for logID 3. So it should show as P5734  Project2 R. Anyway thanks a lot bro.. You are a life saver...

Comment: it might be possible, but will need more details on that. Please post as new question. Also please accept this as answer if it resolve your question

Comment: Thanks a lot mate.. Will post as a new question